# Change order of object's UV segments

Tags: uv

Let's say I have a model consisting of 3 UVs.
This is how they are created by default by typing "U" and selecting the top most option "Unwrap":
[image]

But I would like to "reorder" them in a specific order/sequence, where the 1st part would be the last one.

Now, of course, I know I can move them around but that would not guarantee the exact "touching" of their edges (sorry, I do not know how to describe this more correctly): that is the every next UV section would start exactly where the previous one ends - the way it is now.

BTW this is one UV, not 3 separate ones: I'm having these separated by seams edges so the Blender knows they should be separate segments of one UV.

Can anyone tell me if there is some sort of intelligent way how to reorder UVs and yet preserve the way they would still follow one another as I described above (that is: there would be absolutely no gap in between them exactly as it is by default, cos when I am reordering their positions manually it is never that, there always is some tiny micro empty space between them.

Comment: I don't think you can match their UV coordinates perfectly. I once tried to match the coordinates of UVs without a shared mesh vertex using a script, but I remember that very small differences were automatically created.

Comment: Ah, so it is prolly unavoidable you say?